# Java MouseMotionListener and restricting drawn shapes movement

Tags: java, applet

Working on an applet that draws 2 eyes and uses MouseMotionListener to move the they eyes. Also when the mouse exits the content pane, the eyes look straight. The one thing 
I'm struggling with is I can't figure out how to restrict the pupils movements to stay within the eye. Any suggestions you guys have would be great.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class WatchMe extends JApplet
{
  private int leftMouseX = 130;
  private int leftMouseY = 155;
  private int rightMouseX = 305;
  private int rightMouseY = 155;
  private boolean mouseEntered;

  //init method
  public void init()
  {
    //set background to green
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);

    //add mouse listener
    addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());

    //add a motion listener
    addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseMotionListener());
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    //call superclass paint method
    super.paint(g);

    //draw left eye
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(75, 100, 150, 150);

    //draw left pupil
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(leftMouseX, leftMouseY, 40, 40);

    //draw right eye
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(250, 100, 150, 150);

    //draw right pupil
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(rightMouseX, rightMouseY, 40, 40);

    //checks to see if the mouse is in the pane, if not
    //sets the x,y coordinates to look straight
    if (! mouseEntered)
    {
      leftMouseX = 130;
      leftMouseY = 155;
      rightMouseX = 305;
      rightMouseY = 155;
      repaint();
    }
  }

  private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
  {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    { 
      mouseEntered = true;
      repaint();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
      mouseEntered = false;
      repaint();
    }
  }

  private class MyMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener
  {  

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
      leftMouseX = e.getX();
      leftMouseY = e.getY();
      rightMouseX = e.getX();
      rightMouseY = e.getY();
      repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
      leftMouseX = e.getX();
      leftMouseY = e.getY();
      rightMouseX = e.getX();
      rightMouseY = e.getY();
      repaint();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start I would recommend putting your eye dimensions in variables as shown below.  This way you reduce the chance of errors when entering the same numbers more than once, and if you later decide to change the eye size or position, you only have to change it once.

```
public static final int LEFT_X = 75;
public static final int LEFT_Y = 100;
public static final int EYE_SIZE = 150;
```

We also need the left pupil to be independent of the mouse (so it doesn't follow the mouse out of the eye) so we'll do this:

```
private leftPupilX = 130;
private leftPupilY = 155;
```

Next you need to determine whether or not the mouse is currently in the left eye. This is what will restrict the pupil to the bounds of the eye.  I've done this in a method for convenience.

```
public void setLeftEye() {
     //Set the X Coord for the pupil
     //Mouse is to the left of the eye
     if(leftMouseX < LEFT_X) {
          leftPupilX = LEFT_X;
     //Mouse is to the right of the eye
     } else if(leftMouseX > LEFT_X + EYE_SIZE) {
          leftPupilX = LEFT_X + EYE_SIZE;
     //Mouse is in eye
     } else {
          leftPupilX = leftMouseX;
     }

     //Set the Y Coord for the pupil
     //Mouse is above the eye
     if(leftMouseY < LEFT_Y) {
          leftPupilY = LEFT_X;
     //Mouse is below the eye
     } else if(leftMouseY > LEFT_Y + EYE_SIZE) {
          leftPupilY = LEFT_Y + EYE_SIZE;
     //Mouse is in eye
     } else {
          leftPupilY = leftMouseY;
     }
}
```

Finally you'll need to update the code that draws the left pupil to reflect the variable change, and actually call our new method.

```
//draw left pupil
setLeftEye();
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.fillOval(leftPupilX, leftPupilY, 40, 40);
```

These changes should make the left eye track your mouse the way you described.  You'll need to do something similar for the right eye, since it has different coordinates.  If you have any problems, let me know and I will try to help. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out! I implemented the code you suggested and wrote the stuff for the right eye as well and had an issue at first with the pupils still slightly leaving the eyes, just to the edge of the 'invisible' bounding box around the eye. I made some minor modifications and got it to where it should be. Thank you again for your help, I really appreciate it.